# Strapi database error SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' targetAttribute?.target === uid

Tags: node.js, strapi

I've update my Strapi version from 4.3.6 to 4.4.5 and got this error when I start appliation with production environment with command `npm run start`

```
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). The promise rejected with the reason:
/home/megapolisgit/megapolis-platform/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/morph-relations.js:15
      targetAttribute?.target === uid &&
                      ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/megapolisgit/megapolis-platform/node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/index.js:21:66)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
```

node version is 17.9.1
db: PostgreSQL 14.2

I've checked github repository for answer but haven't found the same issues

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found an answer. The problem was in PM2 I used to run my strapi. By default, PM2 takes node binary from `/usr/bin/node` in my case it was 12.22.12. Using NVM I've installed 18.12.1 but the path to this was different.  I changed ecosystem.config.js to this

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'app',
      script: 'npm',
      args: 'start',
      env_production: {
       NODE_ENV: "production"
      },
      interpreter: "/home/mega/.nvm/versions/node/v18.12.1/bin/node"
    },
  ],
};
```

and got my application running with the correct node version.

Answer (score 0):

Check your node version and switch to latest one

Comment: I switched to 18.12.1 and got the same error but in another place
node_modules/@strapi/database/lib/entity-manager/index.js:65
0|app  |   if (isArray(data) || isString(data) || isNumber(data) || isNull(data) || data?.id) {
0|app  |                                                                                 ^
0|app  | SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'